# How to I do a plm regression for categorical regression (panel data)?

Tags: r, categorical-data, panel-data, plm

I'm wondering if I can use categorical dependent variables in a panel data regression? 
Currently I'm using plm for continuous or clogit for binary dependent variables, e.g.

```
model_income <- plm(income ~ education + age + children, data = incomedata, model = "random") 
model_death <- clogit(death ~ food + medicine + workouts, data = deathdata, method = "approximate")
```

But how about a categorical dependent variable such as

```
religion ~ education + placeofbirth
```

where religion can be buddhist, catholic, protestant, muslim, etc.?

Thank you!